# Haproxy stats related clarifications

Tags: haproxy

Attached my stats page screenshot 
[haproxystats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp9tq.png)

Here are my question / clarifications needed:

1. Under "session rate" - Cur - 13 - Does it mean 13 webrequests are being processed?
2. If you see under "sessions" - Cur  - 250 Max 250 Limit 250 - What does it means?

I observed most of the time "sessions" - Cur  values keep more than 200.

Can someone please clarify about these?

Thank you.

Comment: I spent some time to read and understand with this article - https://www.haproxy.com/blog/exploring-the-haproxy-stats-page/ 

But, still I would like to know if in 

sessions” - Cur - 250 Max 250 Limit 250  If cur had reached the limit - What happens with incoming new requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "Cur" means the current rate per second of incoming connections. Whether they're being processed yet is shown in the drilldown metrics when you hover over that metric.
2. This shows the current rate per second is at 250, the most that value has historically reached is 250, and you have a limit on it of 250. Are you using "rate-limit session"?

Here is more information about what happens when the limit is reached: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#rate-limit